# How to reverse two spinners positions?

Tags: android, android-spinner, baseadapter

I'm working on a currencyApp. I have one button and I want to reverse two spinners items in OnClick. I wrote some code but it's not working correctly

```
 fromSpinner.setSelection(toSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
 //toSpinner.setSelection(fromSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

I'll try to explain my problem. For example fromSpinner showing USD and toSpinner EUR. I want to reverse this elements between two spinners. My code is only working for the first spinner. If anyone knows solution please help me thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

You also can do this by taking both positions of both spinners and then switch their position.

Like this:

```
int pos1 = fromSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();    
int pos2 = toSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();    

fromSpinner.setSelection(pos2);    
toSpinner.setSelection(pos1);
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my self

```
 fromSpinner.setSelection(toSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
 toSpinner.setSelection(fromSpinner.getLastVisiblePosition());
```